# MySQL Select Prints TWO records twice?

Tags: mysql, select

MySQL Doubles my results?

```
mysql_select_db("db", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cart_products WHERE cart_id=22");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  print("'.$row['name'].'<br/>");

  }
mysql_close($con);
```

My database:

```
cart_id     name
22      john
22      sarah
```

My printed HTML:

```
john<br />sarah<br />
john<br />sarah<br />
```

instead of

```
john<br />sarah
```

Why does it print four records ?

Comment: what result do you get when you run SELECT * FROM cart_products WHERE cart_id=22?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Tom's question. What happens when you run the SQL query from MySQL? Also, please do a print_r on the result and paste.

Comment: If I run the query in MySQL I get only two records as how it should be

Answer (score 0):

[`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) by default returns both a numeric and an associative array.

Call `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)` to get the expected result.

Comment: Tried this, still get two records duplicated.